# OS X printing to HP Photosmart black only

Tags: macos, printing, colors, hp-photosmart

When you print something to a Photosmart printer in OS X, by default it prints color.  If you want black and white, you have to manually change the settings.  How do I fix it to where it prints black and white by default, and if you want color, you have to change the settings?  More specifically, I want the default to be black and white that uses only the black cartridge.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally figured this out.  To set a default preset, configure the print options how you like them & save it as a preset (or use one of the other presets already available), then **hold down the Option key and click Print**.  Now, that setting will be the default print setting for that printer in all of your apps in OS X.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the presets are not the default.  I have to manually select the preset every time.  I want the "Standard" preset to pick Black & White, or make the saved preset the default.